# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [6, 80]

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I'm failing to process the below code in the pipeline (it's `imblearn` pipepline)

```
features = training_data.loc[:, training_data.columns[:-1]]
labels = training_data.loc[:, training_data.columns[-1:]]


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.2)
```

```
print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
```

The print output for the shapes is: `(80, 6) (80, 1)`

```
algorithms = [   
    svm.LinearSVC(),
    ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(),

]

def train(algorithm, X_train, y_train):
    model = Pipeline([
        ('vect', TfidfVectorizer()),
        ('smote', SMOTETomek()),
        ('chi', SelectKBest(chi2, k=1000)),
        ('classifier', algorithm)
    ])
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    return model

score_dict = {}
algorithm_to_model_dict = {}
for algorithm in algorithms:
    model = train(algorithm, X_train, y_train)
    score = model.score(X_test, y_test)
    score_dict[algorithm] = int(score * 100)
    algorithm_to_model_dict[algorithm] = model
```

The features and labels are all text (I'm doing text analysis).

The exception is being raised from the `fit` call

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @jasonwong it's mentioned in the subject

Comment: Why is your `X_train` has shape `(80, 6)`? Can you use `TfidfVectorizer` on it? Shouldn't your input a corpus (a list of string) ?

Comment: @jasonwong My X_train is all columns (apart of the last 1) from the original data.
and each row looks as follows: `{'A': 'strA', 'B': 'strB', 'C': 'strC'}`

Comment: You cannot process 2d input with `TfidfVectorizer`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you have a text transformer object in your pipeline. The problem with this approach is that the pipeline will pass the whole dataframe to the `TfidfVectorizer`. However, the text transformers of `scikit-learn` expect a 1d input.

Passing a 2d dataframe to `TfidfVectorizer` causes some weird processing where it mistakes the column names as documents. You can check with this simple example:

```py
X = pd.DataFrame({
    'f1': ['This is doc1', 'This is doc2',
           'This is doc3', 'This is doc4', 'This is doc5'],
    'f2': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
})

vec = TfidfVectorizer()
print(vec.fit(X).get_feature_names())

>>> ['f1', 'f2']
```

This explains why the error message states that there is an inconsistent number of samples: the `TfidfVectorizer` thought of the 6 columns in the dataframe to be the samples and their names to be the features.

If you want to use `TfidfVectorizer` in your pipeline, you have to make sure that only the column with the text documents is passed to it. You can achieve this by wrapping it in a [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html?highlight=columntr#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer):

```py
# if only one column needs to be transformed
transformer = ColumnTransformer(
    [('vec', TfidfVectorizer(), column)],   # column should be a string or int
    remainder='passthrough'
)

# if more than one column needs to be transformed (discouraged, see Note below)
transformer = ColumnTransformer(
    [('vec', TfidfVectorizer(), col_1),  # col_1 should be a string or int
     ...
     ('vec', TfidfVectorizer(), col_n)],   # col_n should be a string or int
    remainder='passthrough'
)
```

Replace `column` above with the index or the name of the column the `TfidfVectorizer` has to transform and it will only process this particular column. The `remainder='passthrough'` will make sure the other columns are left as is and are concatenated with the result. You can then use it in your pipeline like this:

```py
model = Pipeline([
    ('vect', transformer),
    ('smote', SMOTETomek()),
    ('chi', SelectKBest(chi2, k=1000)),
    ('classifier', algorithm)
])
```

---

**Note**

If you have to transform several columns with text, you should consider merging the column entries into a single, combined document and only transform this combined document. Otherwise, each column will be treated with a new vocabulary, although these might overlap to some extent, and you might end up with a very high dimensionality / a lot of features.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion as follows:
`transformer = ColumnTransformer([('vec', TfidfVectorizer(), list(features.columns))], remainder='passthrough')`
but I'm still getting similar error:
`Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [6, 58]`

Comment: When you pass a list of column names/indices to `ColumnTransfer`, it will again pass a 2d dataframe to `TfidfVectorizer`. If you really want to vectorize each column separately, you will have to add one tuple for each column in the transformer list. Will edit the answer to show this.

Comment: However, vectorizing each column separately is not a good option because you might end up with a really large dimensionality, although the vocabulary of each column will probably overlap to some extent. It would probably be better that you combine all records (column values with text) into a single record in a single column.

Comment: I've already tried single column for all text columns - the score was bad

Comment: After using the discouraged approach, I'm getting `ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words`

Comment: This `ValueError` is a completely different problem and relates to the data itself, and not the transformers or the way they are set up. This happens for example if your documents consist of a simple word/character like `a` and not a sentence. You can also refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928769/python-tfidfvectorizer-throwing-empty-vocabulary-perhaps-the-documents-only-c)